# C programming -storing characters into ints?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int c;
    while ( (c = getchar ()) != EOF )
        putchar (c);

    return 0;
}
```

So in this program, there is c = getchar (). So i would assume that getchar returns to an integer regardless of what you type?

If that was the case, if I had the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    printf("%c",c);

    return 0;
}
```

It should not work. As if I typed 'y' for example, the getchar function can return to an integer that is 2digits or more and cannot be stored in a char variable. Yet it worked.... In fact, when I type 'f' c becomes f. But why??

Comment: I don't understand the question. `char` is an integer type.

Comment: We do have manual pages - https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar - perhaps read them

Comment: ?? chat is not an integer type? 'y' for example....

Comment: The `char` input works until the `int` returned by `getchar` is `EOF`, and then you cannot distingush it from the `char` value `0xFF`. Just use the type retuned by the function, `int`.

Comment: `'y'` is an integer. On an ASCII system, `'y'` is exactly `121`, for example.

Comment: Yes. But then if you type 'y' for a getchar function then the second program won't be able to assign 121 to y? Then it should not be able to print 'y' for the output?

Comment: @TommyLassa There is no `y` variable in your code. I don't understand the question.

Comment: The reason getchar() returns an int is so it can return EOF (-1) allowing you to detect "End of File".

Comment: y is not a variable..... it is just a character that you type for example. When you run the second program and the program asks for a character, and you type 'y', then the putchar function will return to an integer (in this case 121) and the program will assign this integer to c, a character variable? which won't work?

Comment: @TonyB so in general the getchar function returns to the character that you typed? it is just different with the special case with EOF?

Comment: In `printf("%c",c);` the variable `c` will be promoted to `int` if it is not already `int`. You *can* pass an `int` value for the `%c` format. Be aware that many C library functions use the `int` where newbies except to use `char`, such as `getchar` and `isupper` and `strchr`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "return to", especially in connection with putchar. When you type `y`, then `getchar` will return `'y'` (which can also be written as `121` (decimal) or `0x79` (hex) or `0171` (octal)). This number will be stored in `c`. `char` is an integer type.

Comment: `char` is an integer type, as defined in the [**C Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 6.2.5: *4 There  are  five standard signed  integer types, designated  as `signed  char`, `short int`, `int`, `long  int`, and `long  long  int`.*

Comment: but does  putchar normally returns to the integer that represents the character according to the ASCll system?

Comment: `putchar` usually returns the character written (except when in error) which was/is of the type `int`. [Please read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48szs1c2.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Characters are integers, or rather there are contexts where certain integer values are interpreted as characters. The type `char` is just an integer type in C, so an `int` can hold all values of a `char`.

One reason why `getchar` returns an `int` is because the special value `EOF` is not any of the integer values that represent characters (because if it were, you could not distinguish end of file from such a character being input). Once you have checked that the value returned by `getchar` was not `EOF`, all other possible return values are characters.

Comment: Well, technically `getchar()` results are not always representable by `char`, since `char` usually has a range of -128…+127 and `getchar()` returns 0…255 and EOF on most systems.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Interesting point; the integer values may indeed not be representable, even if the bit patterns (and thus characters) are. I edited the answer to make the weaker statement "all other possible return values are characters".

Answer (score 0):

> So in this program, there is c = getchar (). So i would assume that getchar returns to an integer regardless of what you type?

True.  Detail: `int getchar()` returns not any integer but an `int`.  The return value is either in the `unsigned char` range  (example 0 ... 255) or `EOF`.  `EOF` is a negative value.

---

```
char c = getchar();
printf("%c",c);
```

> ... should not work. As if I typed 'y' for example, the getchar function can return to an integer that is 2 digits or more and cannot be stored in a char variable. Yet it worked.... In fact, when I type 'f' c becomes f. But why??

If the user types <kbd>y</kbd>, the typical reuslt is a valueof 121 (ASCII y).  The `int` in not "2 digits or more".  The `int` is a value store in memory, typical 32-bits.  It is not store as "digits".

The `printf("%c",c);` accepts an `int` as to match the `"%c"`.  As a `char`, `c` goes though integer promotion (to an `int`) before being passed to `printf(char *format, ...)` all it well specified.

The following will typically all print the same. `"%c"` recieves the `int` value, converts it to an `unsigned char` and then print the corresponding character associate with that value.  usually ASCCI `y`.

```
char c = 'y';
printf("%c", c);
printf("%c", 'y');
printf("%c", 121);
printf("%c", 121 + 256);
```

Comment: Best answer. :) I am a beginner so I am real confused about the memory and the value types. thank you.